# Spring WebFlux+Thymeleaf How to display reactive collection size

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-thymeleaf

I am developing a spring boot service to manage a REST server.
The service displays a reactive list on one of the forms.
It is very simple code.

Table in thymeleaf template

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Alive</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
        <td th:text="${item.counterpartID}" />
        <td th:text="${item.counterpartName}" />
        <td th:text="${item.alive}"/>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```java
    @GetMapping("/counterparties")
    public String init(Model model) {
       IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable reactiveDataDrivenMode =
                new ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable( 
                   webClient
                     .get() 
                     .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                        .path("/findAllCounterpart")
                        .build())
                     .retrieve()
                     .bodyToFlux(Counterpart.class)
                  , 1);
       model.addAttribute("items", reactiveDataDrivenMode);
       return "counterparties.html";
    }
```

Now I want to display collection size (numbers of rows in table).
I added to the html temlate tag

```html
<label th:text="'total rows: ' + ${#lists.size(items)}">rows number in table</label>
```

And I got an unexpected result

```
total rows: 1
```

How to display the real number of rows in a reactive collection ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use javascript.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function countLoadedRows() {
    var table = document.getElementById('tableId');
    var tbodyRowCount = table.tBodies[0].rows.length;
    console.log('total rows: ' + tbodyRowCount);
    document.getElementById('totalRowsId').textContent = tbodyRowCount
    }
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', countLoadedRows)
</script>
```

and html tags is

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "countLoadedRows()" value = "Total rows: "><label id="totalRowsId">???</label>

<table id="tableId">
...
</table>
```